# VaR Backtesting. High frequency of exceedances

Tags: backtesting, portfolio, value-at-risk

I'm preparing for thesis defense and I've got simple question connected with Value at Risk backtesting. Portfolio VaR was calculated using historical simulation approach (250 days and 500days) and backtested with Kupiec test. In those portfolios where VaR was not properly estimated, there was always high frequency of exceedances so the Value at Risk was underestimated.

Why there was so many exceedances? The statistical important information was included in tails of distribution, because of lack of these tails the VaR was not properly estimated?

What should be done to improve the precision of estimation?

Comment: What kind of products does your portfolio contain? If there are non-linear instruments (e.g. options), then the historical VaR might not be suitable to capture the non-linearity of options payoff.

Comment: Portfolios contain only shares.

Comment: Hi Jeje. Few things that are nice to know. So you have 500 numbers, i.e. the daily returns, for how many shares? So are you using the T squared law to scale the time horizon? What is the confidence level you are using?

Comment: I got time series 1200 observations, based on 250 or 500 quotations. I used both 0.9 and 0.95 confidence intervals. Every portfolio contains 5 different companies. I know there will be only theoretical question how to lower the number of exceedances :/ but my supervisor didn't help me. He said only something about lack of distribution tails.

Comment: All right Rafal, sorry I called you Jeje. Sorry about your supervisor. Well you need to have good consistent data if you want to have good consistent results. Make sure all your data lines up in chronological order. Just to make sure, I assume you would not make that kind of rookie mistake. So how many shares do you have in your data? You say you have 1200 observations, and you only use 250 or 500 of them, why is that, why not 600 to 1200 then?

Comment: Well, I should write more informations. Sorry about that. I was  doing daily portfolio optimization using Value at Risk with HS approach. I did it on 30 portfolios and i made 4 different cases for VaR 0.05 250 or 500 days, and VaR 0.1 250 or 500days. All calculations were checked by my supervisor and were fine for him. The best was the case based on 0.05 alpha and 500 days, other models were worse with VaR estimation, and here's the point. He told that, he will ask me why in other models were more exceedances when I was backtesting, and what could I do to improve this models.

Comment: All right Rafal. What is the time horizon of your VaR?

Comment: And please define exceedances.

Comment: This is daily VaR, calculated from last 250 or 500 quotations depends on the case. Exceedances were for me, number of days when the loss was higher than forecasted VaR from previous day.

Comment: All right Rafal. I am getting closer to being able to answer your question. But I really want to know why you did not use 600 to 1200 since you had that data?

Comment: I have the data from 2011 to 2016. VaR was calculated till the end of 2016 starting from the beginning of 2012 or 2013. Depends if it was calculated based on 250 or 500 days. I did it because I had to. Supervisor told me, that I have to calculate Value at Risk in this way.

Comment: All right. I'm going to lunch. But will be back later today to answer your question. Do you know why he asked you to do it this way? .. sorry how curious I am? How much of the data do you use in each case, do you use the rest of the data in the backtesting or something like that?

Comment: I have no idea, why he told me to do it in this way.. I was often surprised with his "advices" or "guidelines". I wasn't using the rest of the data in the backtesting. I used only calculated VaR and next day rate of return to check if there is an exceedance.

Comment: Hi Rafal. It's quite hard for me to answer this question without guessing, because I don't have the dataset and I can't read or test the code that processes the dataset.  But I will guess instead and hope that it will be helpful. Is that ok with you? If not, then I need more information.

Comment: Of course it's ok for me. I think your theoretical point of view will be helpfull.

Comment: Do you think it is possible that your supervisor wanted you to have this problem? Was it him that gave you the dataset?

Comment: Not really, this dataset was randomly selected by me.

Comment: All right then we can eliminate that he wanted you to have this problem.

Comment: How many exceedances do you have for each case?

Comment: Number of observations 1009
Number w exceedances 103
example portfolio when alpha was 0.1. So I think this was ok :)
But there are examples when I've got about 130 exceedances so VaR was underestimated, and my supervisor wanna know what could be done to improve this particular model in theory

Comment: 1009 observations, 1009 consecutive days, contradicts what you said earlier about how much of the data was used or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: well I said i used data from years 2011-2016. This was the whole time period where I was calculating VaR.

Comment: All right, looks like you used all the data, that is good :D. Have to go out for some errands, will answer later today.

Comment: Ok :) Ill be waiting

Comment: Please add this extra information to the question not just the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the problem can be boiled down into:

> > > SAMPLE SIZE

If I am right, this problem should be less where you are using 500 daily returns in you VaR calculation instead of 250. Then the reason is that the statistical parameters become fuzzier and fuzzier with fewer samples.

A simple way to make it better is to make it grow i.e. make it remember. Allow it to grow never to shrink, then it remembers volatile times.

Comment: Thank you, I also thought about sample size. But I think that, I should also take into consideration the simple optimization routine in Excel. Because the case where I was using 500days for VaR calculations produced better estimation (less rejections in Kupiec test).  Supervisor told me that the simple solver-optimization will be fine. But now I'm thinking that there is also  probably also a problem. For single stocks, the model based on 250days was much better, but for optimized portfolios better was the model based on 500days

Comment: Could you tell me, what do you mean by "make it remember'?

Comment: Lets say if you make the 250 day window grow for each day, so for the first observation it is 250 days, the second it is 251 days, and third observation it is 252 you get the point, so you only add historical information to it and never take it, that is one way to make it remember.

Comment: Ok :) Now I understand,  so after 250+X days, the VaR will be calculated based on historical data from 250+X days

Comment: Yes, and please accept my answer above if you think it is correct.